# Why does Drools throw an IllegalAccessError when jitting?

Tags: drools

I'm getting the following stack trace when using drools (latest version - 7.32):

> "stack_trace":"java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
>   org/drools/core/rule/constraint/ASMConditionEvaluatorJitter$EvaluateMethodGenerator$CoercingComparisonType
>   at ConditionEvaluator5003d21b2c7846fb81f75c4b75fe103a.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint.evaluate(MvelConstraint.java:275)

The error seems to occur randomly, and restarting the application fixes it (at least for a time). I tried updating to the latest drools version as I could see recent activity in the class (https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/commits/master/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/rule/constraint/ASMConditionEvaluatorJitter.java) - but it didn't help.

Does anyone know what might cause this kind of stack trace? (bearing in mind it works find after restart or recreating the same kbase). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, without more details we cannot investigate.

File a bug on https://issues.jboss.org/ and provide us a reproducer please.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks. I reverted to drools 7.24 and this seems to have resolved the issue based on today's testing. I'll try and isolate the offending rule in a reproducer and submit an issue.